# php foreach replace variables

Tags: php, foreach, str-replace

I want to use a template file, where i am using {value} as markers to replace that with a value.

The variable is set like $order and I want to replace it in the template where there is {order}.

There are about 50 of these variables I want to replace.

Is there a way to do this automaticly?

```
$text = file_get_contents("bol_files/order_template.txt");
    $text = str_replace("{ordernummer}",$bestelnummer, $text);
    $text = str_replace("{verzendwijze}",$verzendwijze, $text);
    echo $text;
```

Comment: I think you may need to use `preg_replace` where it will replace all the occurences of `{blah}` with `$blah`

Comment: no, `preg_replace()` is wrong idea here

Comment: can you please revisit the answers and either accept the one that solved your problem or update your question to explain why none of the answers helped to solve your problem so people get a chance to update their answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str_replace can take arrays as arguments:

```
$text = str_replace(array_keys($replaceArray), $replacearray, $text);
```

where $replaceArray is an associative array

```
$replaceArray = (
  "{ordernummer}" => $bestelnummer,
  "{verzendwijze}" => $verzendwijze,
 and so on
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function.

```
$text = file_get_contents("bol_files/order_template.txt");
$trans = array(
    '{ordernummer}' => $bestelnummer, 
    '{verzendwijze}'   => $verzendwijze,
    ......
);
echo strtr($text, $trans);
```

***Update:***
If your rule is fixed (replace `{var_name}` with `$var_name`), then you could use regex replace.

```
echo preg_replace('/\{([^}]+)\}/e',  '${\'$1\'}' , $text );
```

***[Check the example.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/enxWZ0)***

***Addition:*** but `e` marker is deprecated (you could use `preg_replace_callback` instead, but in that way, you need to import these variables into the scope of the callback function), I think you'd better hold the data in an array instead of separate variables, even if you could use `get_defined_vars`.

Comment: Thanks xdazz. Only is there a way to avoid that i need to type all te 50 varibles in dat trans array?

Comment: @user1595774 Check my update, it will replace `{var_name}` with `$var_name`.

Comment: `/e` marker is deprecated since it poses a security risk. It will be removed from PHP. See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_preg_replace_eval_modifier

Comment: @Gordon Yes, but if you use `preg_replace_callback`, you need to import these variables into the scope of the callback function.

Comment: @xdazz well, yes, but at least that will work in a future version of PHP while suggesting to use `\e` won't because it will be removed soon.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, i agree with you, for the op's case, it's better to hold the data in an array instead of separate variables, even if you could use `get_defined_vars`.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, **the easiest would be to collect the template vars in an array in the first place** instead of using individual variables. Then you could simply pass the array as a whole to `str_replace`.

If the above is not an option, you could use

- [`get_defined_vars` — Returns an array of all defined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

#### Example:

```
$a = 'foo';
$b = 'bar';
$c = 'baz';

$template = '{a} to the {b} to the {c}';

foreach (get_defined_vars() as $key => $val) {
     if (is_scalar($val)) {
         $template = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $val, $template);
     }
}
echo $template; // prints 'foo to the bar to the baz';
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6IcWO2)

#### Alternative that does the same:

```
$a = 'foo';
$b = 'bar';
$c = 'baz';

$template = '{a} to the {b} to the {c}';

$scopeVars = array_filter(get_defined_vars(), 'is_scalar');
$templateMarker = preg_replace('/^.*$/', '{$0}', array_keys($scopeVars));
echo str_replace($templateMarker, $scopeVars, $template);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AC7xxk)

But note that this is potentially insecure when you let other people provide the template markers in the template. Since `get_defined_vars` gets you all the vars *in the current scope*, someone could try to guess variables that are not template values which might potentially contain sensitive data. Up to you to evaluate that risk.

Also note that I have added a check to see whether the scope variables hold a scalar value because if there is objects or arrays in the scope vars, PHP will complain about not being able to convert those to strings in `str_replace`.

Comment: Its no securtity issue for me. how do i get te complete string with replaced varibled to echo to my page?